# sqlite - filtering out duplicate rows based on condition

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a dataset that looks like this.

```
id,timestamp,source,action,data_id
1,<time in ms>,external,add,1257
2,<time in ms>,internal,update,1134
3,<time in ms>,external,remove,1257
4,<time in ms>,external,add,1259
```

What I want to do is run a SELECT query and get all rows WHERE action IS add except those where action is remove.

In the above dataset, the query `SELECT * FROM table WHERE action = 'add'` will return rows 1 and 4. I want to filter out row 1 since in row 3 it has action remove. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using exists logic:

```sql
SELECT id, timestamp, source, action, data_id
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE
    action = 'add' AND
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM yourTable t2
                WHERE t2.data_id = t1.data_id AND
                      t2.action = 'remove');
```

Read in plain English, the above query will return all records for each `data_id`, provided that there *not* exist one record for the same `data_id` whose action is "remove."

Regarding performance, you might find that the following index helps:

```sql
CREATE INDEX idx ON yourTable (action, data_id, source, timestamp);
```

Comment: This works except when there is at least one record where action is remove, but this won't return any result when there are no records with action 'remove'

Comment: I disagree, it should return all records when each group does _not_ have a "remove" record.

Comment: I created a dummy db where records have either action "add" or "update". No record has action "remove". When I run this query I get no result.

Comment: Can you paste the demo link here?

Comment: My bad! I was missing `action = 'add'` after the WHERE clause

Comment: Actually I didn't have that requirement in my original answer, but then again, you still should have been getting _some_ records back.

Comment: I have given you an index option.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with MAX() window function:

```
select id,timestamp,source,action,data_id
from (
  select *, max(action = 'remove') over (partition by data_id) flag
  from tablename
  where action in ('add', 'remove')
)
where flag = 0
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=5f5bd2d2e926a41c84cb457c04d3e73b).
Results:

```
> id | timestamp    | source   | action | data_id
> -: | :----------- | :------- | :----- | ------:
>  4 | <time in ms> | external | add    |    1259
```